CORS error from express calling api from subdomain
I have this error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mysite.com/api/uploadfile' from origin 'https://sub.mysite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I use a subdomain and it seems not to like it when calling the API.   I looked at similar StackOverflow questions but didn't resolve my issue.
works for other API calls but failed for the file upload route.
I am running express for middleware
   //allow all
    this.app.use(cors()); 

   //file upload route looks like this
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
    this.router.post("/", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),  
                          upload.single('file'), 
                          this.fileController.uploadfile); 

I am running angular for client-side
uploadFile(formData: any): Observable<any> {
    // test 1
    // return Axios.post(`${this.apiURL}test`, formData, {
    //     headers: {
    //         'Authorization': this._authService.accessToken,
    //         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
    //     }
    // })
    // .pipe(
    //     tap((response: any) => {
    //         console.log("response:", response)
    //     })
    // );

    // test 2
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
            'Authorization': this._authService.accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'   
        })
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiURL}test`, formData, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        tap((response: any) => {
            console.log("response:", response)
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );

}


Please see if this post helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631739/cors-error-when-multipart-form-data-was-added-to-request-header

@WeDoTheBest4You thanks but that didn't help

Is the issue still persisting.

@WeDoTheBest4You yes it is.  it's the load balancer issue using the subdomain.  I am working on a different solution.
